# Securely amplifying/extending my WiFi signal using TP-Link WA5210G

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

One room of my house gets a very bad wifi signal (the strength is lower and it results in frequent packet drops). I had an old outdoor access point lying around - [TP-Link WA5210G](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/outdoor-radio/tl-wa5210g/) - using which I'm trying to extend/amplify the Wifi signal.

In the past I've used this device using a wired Ethernet cable (PoE) and it worked beautifully. This time, I don't want to clutter my home with ugly Ethernet cables, so I'm looking for wireless solution.

I chose the obvious "universal repeater mode" in the device, but strangely, in this mode, it only [supports WEP encryption](https://www.tp-link.com/latam/support/faq/348/). When I tried enabling WEP encryption on my base router (a Huaewei device provided by my ISP), I ran into the following issues:

- big fat warnings in Mac OS about WEP being completely insecure
- strange hex keys which would make it very hard to share the wifi password with guests

Hence, the question. **What is a secure way to get this done?** The TP-Link device has so many different modes, which to me, sound like they all do the same thing.

I even tried the [AP Client mode](https://www.tp-link.com/lk/support/faq/289/). Here I  needed to provide the main network's SSID (or MAC) along with it's passphrase, which made me think it's trying to do some extending/amplifying, but it didn't work as expected.

- After rebooting the device the status page (and the indicators on the back) indicated that some sort of Wifi signal was enabled, but I could not see any new SSID being broadcasted.
- I was sitting right next to the TP-Link device and connected to my main/base network's SSID and noticed that that the BSSID and MAC address (of the access point), was still the old one.

Comment: You don't want the **AP Client Mode**.  I think that the **Repeater mode is correct**.  Because of WEP, you may have to get another newer device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RohitGupta. What _does_ the **AP Client Mode** actually do? Why was it asking for the base SSID/MAC and passphrase?

Comment: AP Client Mode allows the AP to become a client for another wireless AP - in a sense it turns it to a wireless adapter card. Repeater mode is a wireless range extender, i.e. what you're looking for. Due to piss-poor security WEP was superseded early 2000s by WPA - which itself was proven insecure a decade ago, and was superseded by current WPA2. AFAIK there's still no standard for how range extenders work, so devices from diff mfg:s don't necessarily work together. I'd contact my ISP to get a compatible range extender. If you extend the range, you shouldn't see a new SSID being broadcast.

Comment: The client mode creates a different AP. Again, you want repeater - same SSID - that extends the *range* of the current AP and allows roaming (you don't know where your devices are connecting to and you don't need to know, that's how repeaters should work). And indeed you may need a new device.

Comment: If I'm alright with creating a new SSID and manually selecting the network based on the room I'm sitting in, how do I go about doing that?